# Deploy Docker Image To Heroku with Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I recently tried to move away from Azure for my .NetCore hosting and deployment to Heroku as a cost effective alternative. I'm still in the 'try it out' phase and I'm nearly done with my CI/CD process to get my app up and running in Heroku, but I'M struggling to get it deployed via dpl.

Here is what my current .yml file looks like (NOTE: I know it needs to be split up into more stages, right now I'm just experimenting):

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
    - builddeploy

build:
    stage: builddeploy
    services:
        - docker:dind
    before_script:
        - apk update
        - apk add ruby-dev ruby-rdoc
        - gem install dpl
    script:
        - docker build -t aspnetapp -f Dockerfile .
        - docker login --username=$HEROKU_USERNAME --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
        - docker tag aspnetapp registry.heroku.com/[app_name]/web
        - docker push registry.heroku.com/[app_name]/web
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=[app_name] --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
```

Everything works without a hitch, however on the last step, which is the `dpl` command, it says:

I wont mind using the Heroku CLI directly but can't seem to find a good way to install it on this Alpine based docker image. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image]